# Get the latest 5 row date from MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Only 5 title;
that is my table :

```
ID   Title   Time
1    DA-UB   2017-05-14 15:02:03
2    UB-SA   2017-05-14 15:03:03
3    ER-UB   2017-05-14 15:04:03
4    DA-UB   2017-05-14 15:05:03
5    UB-sa   2017-05-14 15:06:03
6    ER-UB   2017-05-14 15:07:03
7    OR-SA   2017-05-14 15:10:03
8    ER-DA   2017-05-14 15:11:03
```

I want see this(last added 5 row)

```
4    DA-UB   2017-05-14 15:05:03
5    UB-sa   2017-05-14 15:06:03
6    ER-UB   2017-05-14 15:07:03
7    OR-SA   2017-05-14 15:10:03
8    ER-DA   2017-05-14 15:11:03
```

Comment: Could you share your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIMIT`:

```
select *
from your_table
order by time desc 
limit 5
```

#### EDIT:

As per latest update in the comments below, you can use a limited correlated query to get the latest row per title and then limit the result to 5 rows.

```
select *
from your_table t1
where id = (
        select id
        from your_table t2
        where t1.title = t2.title
        order by time desc
        limit 1
        )
order by time desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: i need group on title

Comment: @Darkhanbayr - How do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: @Darkhanbayr . . . This answers your question.  You should accept this answer and ask another question, if you have further refinements that would change the answer.

Comment: @Darkhanbayr - Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 5
      * 
FROM
     [YourTable]
ORDER BY 
      Time DESC
```